# Php function serialize() returns s:value but i don't want this 's:'.What should I do?

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I got this as an O/P:

s:287:"a:3:{s:6:"actors";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Actors";s:5:"value";s:38:"Felicity Jones, Diego Luna, Alan Tudyk";}s:8:"director";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Director";s:5:"value";s:14:"Gareth Edwards";}s:6:"writer";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Writer";s:5:"value";s:36:"Chris Weitz, Tony Gilroy, John Knoll";}}";

My Code:-

```
<?php
$arr = array("actors"=>array("name"=>"Actors","value"=>"Curt Clendenin, Michael Ornelas, Keaton Shyler, David Uchansky"),"director"=>array("name"=>"Director","value"=>"Colin Fleming, John Garside"),"writer"=>array("name"=>"Writer","value"=>"Colin Fleming (story), John Garside (story), Jerry Renek (story)"));
$sarr = serialize($arr);
add_post_meta(1,'_attributes',$sarr);
?>
```

I don't need first s:287" but this thing automatically save in my database. Help me please..

Comment: Can you show your code, it looks like you are serializing something which is already serialize.

Comment: I got this output in my database. I need this as o/p in database:a:3:{s:6:"actors";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Actors";s:5:"value";s:38:"Felicity Jones, Diego Luna, Alan Tudyk";}s:8:"director";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Director";s:5:"value";s:14:"Gareth Edwards";}s:6:"writer";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Writer";s:5:"value";s:36:"Chris Weitz, Tony Gilroy, John Knoll";}}";

Comment: Add that to your question and format it properly please. It is unreadable in the comments like that. Use the "edit" button just under your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @ADyson, you can see it in the question. In question, you can see the o/p which i gotten but if you remove s:287" & then you see that remaining is the o/p which i want...Thank You..

Comment: Ok thanks. Now you need to show the code which generates it. We can't tell you how to alter it if we can't see how you created it

Comment: Now you can see the code.@ADyson

Comment: Don't manually serialize the array before passing it to `add_post_meta()` (remove `$sarr = serialize($arr);`). The function `add_post_meta()` will serialize the data for you (which means that it now get's serialized twice, hence the `s:287`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The WordPress function [add_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) tries to serialize the passed data for itself.

```
$arr = [
    'actors' => [
        'name' => 'Actors',
        'value' => 'Curt Clendenin, Michael Ornelas, Keaton Shyler, David Uchansky',
    ],
    'director' => [
        'name' => 'Director',
        'value' => 'Colin Fleming, John Garside',
    ],
    'writer' => [
        'name' => 'Writer',
        'value' => 'Colin Fleming (story), John Garside (story), Jerry Renek (story)',
    ],
];

// just store it as it is - wordpress does the rest
add_post_meta(1, '_attributes', $sarr);
```

As you can see in the documentation of `add_post_meta()` it calls internally the [add_metadata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_metadata/) function. This function checks for data, that has to be serialized by calling [maybe_serialize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_serialize/). For BC reasons it doubly serializes already serialzed strings as mentioned in the comments of the function.

Conclusion: Just pass the unserialzed array to the `add_post_meta()` function.